# JSON exception and permissions

Tags: android, json, permissions

I have written app for weather using open weather API.... but when i install the app in my phone and click on the button to determine weather it crashes... I use Android M in my phone

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while(data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;

        }
        //combined the exceptions MalformedURL and IOException to a common to display a toast msg
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            String msg = "";
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);
            for(int i = 0;i<arr.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String main = "";
                String desc = "";

                main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                desc = jsonPart.getString("description");
                icon = jsonPart.getString("icon");

                if (main != "" && desc != "") {
                    msg += main + "\r\n" + desc;
                }

            }

            if(msg != ""){
                weatherReport.setText(msg);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Location not able to determine",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Location not able to determine",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The error shown is that arr.length() is applied on a null array....
i don't get what the error is . is it about permissions ... if so how should i implement permissions in Marshmallow... this is the code that is inside onCreate(), if its about permissions pls tell how to implement..

```
try {

                    //to hide the keyboard after pressing the button
                    InputMethodManager manager =
                            (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    manager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(weatherInput.getWindowToken(),0);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    //used to encode the entered input for url.. for example San Fransisco appears in url
                    //as San%20Fransisco ... and to enable that we use the encoder...
                    String encodedCity = URLEncoder.encode(city,"UTF-8");

                    downloadTask.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCity);

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Logcat ..

```
02-25 22:56:54.009 1413-1413/com.example.hemantj.weather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.hemantj.weather, PID: 1413
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                                           at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                                           at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                                           at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                                           at com.example.hemantj.weather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:133)
                                                                           at com.example.hemantj.weather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:92)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post log cat here

Comment: also post your JSON

Comment: replace this line  JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo); with  JSONArray arr = new weatherInfo.getJSONArray(0); or for multiple data use for loop

Comment: posted log cat.. pls answer now..and also note that i am using ANDROID TARGET SDK as 25 and min SDK as 23..

Answer (score 1):

```
 try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: this inner of post" + getcontent_for_validate);
                    jsonobj = new JSONObject(getcontent_for_validate);
                    System.out.println("this is get content" + jsonobj.toString());


                    JSONArray array = jsonobj.getJSONArray("Staff_Details");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        Clint_id = editText_user_name.getText().toString();
                        Api_key = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("api_key");
                       COMPANY_LOGO = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("company_logo");
                        Password = editText_password.getText().toString();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**internet permission only**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

error is in your onPostExecute()

```
new JSONArray(weatherInfo);  //is returning null

so arr is null
```

what is value of weatherInfo?

Comment: weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");